# Is there a way to make recursive SQL queries without using a CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use the results I get from the following CTE as a select statement so I can nest it inside another query - as far as I understand, you can't use CTEs nested in a query;

```
WITH cte_exp AS
(
    select
        [PrimaryKey],
        [SelfKey]
    from
        MyTable
    where PrimaryKey = 1

    UNION ALL

    select
        i.[PrimaryKey],
        i.[SelfKey]
    from
        MyTable i
        inner join cte_exp cte
            on cte.PrimaryKey = i.SelfKey
)
SELECT 'AAA' AS StandardEntry, [PrimaryKey]
FROM   cte_exp
```

From MyTable -

```
PrimaryKey | SelfKey
--------------------
     1         null
     2           1
     3         null
     4           2
     5           4
     6           3
     7           2
```

Will produce:

```
StandardEntry | PrimaryKey
--------------------------
    AAA            1
    AAA            2
    AAA            4
    AAA            7
    AAA            5
```

But I want to be able to harness this tabular output and insert it into another pre-existing table so something like:

```
INSERT INTO AnotherTable ([StandardEntry],[Key]) select * from  ( ... the cte as above ... )
```

Do I need to create it as a stored procedure or is there a way I can wrap up a CTE

A view is no good; having the PrimaryKey selector `where PrimaryKey = 1` outside of the cte just results in one row instead of the expected 5, that variable needs to be injected in the first select statement)

Comment: As a general rule a CTE can be nested into another query. SQL Server may only implement some cases of it, though.

Comment: Yeah I realised as soon as I posted the question the syntax outside of the CTE is really basic. Now I'm trying to figure out how to delete from a table using the values produced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't *nest* CTEs, but they can be part of the `insert`:

```
with cte as (
      . . . 
     )
insert into . . .
   select . . .
   from cte;
```

You can see this in the syntax diagram for [`insert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Note that in most databases, CTEs are part of the `select`, so you can do what you want.

Comment: Yup I literally just realised this as soon as I posted the question, dammit, was going to delete but you answered already :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query multiple levels of data without recursion then i'd recommend looking into the hierarchyid data type.